# Need formula to ignore zero

Tags: excel-formula

Need help to have this formula ignore zero values as being the min value.

```
=IF(L4="",INDEX($D$3:$K$3,MATCH(MIN(D4:K4),D4:K4,0)),HLOOKUP(L4,$D$2:$K$3,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: Use MINIFS() instead of MIN()?

Comment: How would I incorporate the MINIFS() into this formula?

Comment: Could you please share a sample of the data you are using? This would help.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott points out replace:

```
MIN(D4:K4)
```

with:

```
MINIFS(D4:K4,D4:K4,"<>0")
```

*(just insert this as a replacement)*
`MINIFS()` by itself, does not require array-entry.